# Capture screen of the application on a Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c#, screenshot, win-universal-app

I need to capture the screen of my application to save it on the device. Is it possible with a Windows 10 Universal App?

Comment: Have you tried It with a normal screenshot api?

Answer (score 3):

If your app runs specifically on phones then it can use the [ScreenCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.screencapture.aspx) class from the Phone Contract. This isn't available on other device families.

On other devices you can capture the apps own window contents (but not others) by rendering it into an offscreen bitmap. For a Xaml app use the [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) class to render the root of the page.

```
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(); 
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(pageRoot, width, height);
```

Extract the image with GetPixelsAsync, encode to a bitmap (jpg, png, etc) with a BitmapEncoder then save or  share the results.